# Keycloak Update / Delete client after dynamic client registration

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak dynamic client registration works fine:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/clients-registrations/default \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"clientId": "myclient"}'
```

As a response I receive the client representation with especially the registrationAccessToken:

```
{
  "id": "4c6c36d0-6a53-41d9-be37-46bd0d67ebd2",
  "clientId": "myclient",
  "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "secret": "1f85aa4e-6cdc-4f6c-83ba-f3c67d4561f2",
  "registrationAccessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2YWIyYTVjZC0xNjgwLTQ5MTYtYmUzYi0wZmFmMjVmZDczMzQifQ.eyJqdGkiOiI3YjVlMjE5Ny0yZjA5LTQwNTgtYmU0ZC02MDM1M2QzMGFkNWIiLCJleHAiOjAsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTg0NTQxNTY5LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvOTQ5IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zLzk0OSIsInR5cCI6IlJlZ2lzdHJhdGlvbkFjY2Vzc1Rva2VuIiwicmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX2F1dGgiOiJhbm9ueW1vdXMifQ.NCqZ6yJrKz9t3vs65kwM88PNvsZMmxig3vqOmc_iLyE",
  "redirectUris": [],
  "webOrigins": [],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "bearerOnly": false,
  "consentRequired": false,
  "standardFlowEnabled": true,
  "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": false,
  "serviceAccountsEnabled": false,
  "publicClient": false,
  "frontchannelLogout": false,
  "protocol": "openid-connect",
  "attributes": {},
  "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
  "fullScopeAllowed": true,
  "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
  "defaultClientScopes": [
    "web-origins",
    "role_list",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "email"
  ],
  "optionalClientScopes": [
    "address",
    "phone",
    "offline_access",
    "microprofile-jwt"
  ]
}
```

According the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#keycloak-representations) one should be able to read, update and delete the client with the registrationAccessToken:

> It will return a Client Representation that also includes the registration access token. You should save the registration access token somewhere if you want to retrieve the config, update or delete the client later.

However, when trying to read the just created client, I receive a 401 Unothorized when using the registrationAccessToken received from registration.

```
curl --request GET \
     --url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/clients-registrations/default/4c6c36d0-6a53-41d9-be37-46bd0d67ebd2 \
     --header 'authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI2YWIyYTVjZC0xNjgwLTQ5MTYtYmUzYi0wZmFmMjVmZDczMzQifQ.eyJqdGkiOiI3YjVlMjE5Ny0yZjA5LTQwNTgtYmU0ZC02MDM1M2QzMGFkNWIiLCJleHAiOjAsIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTg0NTQxNTY5LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwODAvYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvOTQ5IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zLzk0OSIsInR5cCI6IlJlZ2lzdHJhdGlvbkFjY2Vzc1Rva2VuIiwicmVnaXN0cmF0aW9uX2F1dGgiOiJhbm9ueW1vdXMifQ.NCqZ6yJrKz9t3vs65kwM88PNvsZMmxig3vqOmc_iLyE'

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Not authorized to view client. Not valid token or client credentials provided."
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from:

```
--url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/clients-registrations/default/4c6c36d0-6a53-41d9-be37-46bd0d67ebd2 \
```

to:

```
--url http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/myrealm/clients-registrations/default/myclient \
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't got die idea to try with the client ID instead of the ID, despite it is written that way in the documentation.
However, this behavior is kinda weird. When using the admin REST API, you have always to use the ID, not die client ID (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource). When using `clients-registations` one have to use die client ID and not the ID. This is, what got me to use the ID.